# Assigning numbers to the new components in Altium designer?

Tags: schematics, altium

I am drawing a schematics in Altium designer. I have several schematics (sheets) in my current project. Some of the components have already a designator numbers like R5, C20, L13 ... etc.

But some new components does not have yet, and it is like R?, C?, L? ...etc.

My question: How to make numbers to these new components ? Can one assign numbers to all these components at once ?

Comment: Tools->Annotate Schematic; And Tools->Board Level Annotate. Google or the Help function can tell you more. Too lazy to type it all out right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to annotate just the new components is to go to `Tools -> Annotate Schematics Quietly` and click `Yes`.

Comment: Is it possible to start annotation with a specific number for new components? For example, I have schematics with components and annotations on it, I added new components and I want annotation to start for example R300.

Comment: @MubinIcyer you can set the start index. See here: https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/annotating-design-components